# Asynchronous tasks on a Timer. How to avoid overlapping?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety

I am requesting messages from a server every {n} seconds with a timer.
I'm getting some exceptions that I think are related to my collection of messages not being thread-safe.

I smell there is something fishy but I'm not sure what is the best way to handle it.

The code looks similar to this:

```
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    DoSomething1();    
                    DoSomething2();                     
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogManager.GetLogger(GetType()).Error("Exception caught in " + GetType().Name, ex);
                }
                finally
                {                        
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                }
            }  
        });

    private void DoSomething1()
    {
        messages.AddRange(server.GetMessages());
        ParseMessages();
        messages.Clear();
    }
```

Sometimes when doing AddRange I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Source array was not long enough. Check
>   srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.    at
>   System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array
>   destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean
>   reliable)    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32
>   value)    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32
>   min)    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)

I think it's because the messages list has been modified on another call of the timer?

Comment: Use a thread safe collection like ConcurrentDictionary  or BlockingCollection

Comment: Where's the timer? And please, please, do not use `Thread.Sleep` in the `finally` clause. Just move it after the `try-catch`,

Comment: Yes, no doubt about it.  Two threads are calling List<>.AddRange() at the same time.  You are also randomly losing messages, happens when a thread calls Clear() at the same time another one calls AddRange().  Watch out for System.Timers.Timer, it is very nasty when you use it with its AutoReset property set to true.  That's only safe if the Interval is much, much longer than the job its Elapsed event handler does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple producers in multiple threads, use some kind of locking mechanizm (like `lock` keyword) or better a thread-safe collection from [Thread-Safe Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx). Also make sure `server.GetMessages()` isn't returning `null`.

Comment: I tried using lock(messages) { DoSomething1(): }  and it seems to be working fine now. This way I avoid having to refactor code in comparison to use a thread-safe collection but I take note for next time.

Comment: However, be warned that this will work only for low congestion of thread race conditions - it may happen to slow you down too much or cause dead locks later.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) (an out-of-the-box, built-in thread-safe collection since .NET 4.0) to perform the same job. If you're parsing messages, you may be parsing them in order, thus, FIFO should work for you.